# Spring Security 3 specify multiple intercept-url access roles

Tags: spring-security, url-interception

I am trying to setup Spring 3 security using JDBC auth. Everything is working fine apart from when I try to specify multiple access roles to an intercept-url. Eg I want anyone with the roles ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN to be able to access all pages, I use the follwoing line in my spring config file -

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

However this throws the following error -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ ROLE_ADMIN]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1401)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:558)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:852)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3843)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4342)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [ ROLE_ADMIN]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1460)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1398)
    ... 27 more
```

If specify that only one of the roles can access any url then it is fine (fine for either role). Changing the order in which i specify the roles makes no difference either. It is as though something has changed in Spring Security 3 that now cannot handle mulitple access roles being specified.

I have successfully got this working previously with Spring Security 2, and am using virtually the same configuration. Any ideas?

My security config file is listed below -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
      xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">  

    <security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied.jsp" >    
        <security:form-login
            default-target-url="/app/home"
            always-use-default-target="true" />

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />

        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query='select "username", "password", "enabled"
                    from users where "username" = ?' 
                authorities-by-username-query='select "username", "authority"                       from user_roles where "username" = ?' />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 45):

I had the same issue but used expressions to get around this issue:

You should embed

```xml
use-expressions="true"
```

in your existing config. So:

```xml
<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied.jsp" >
```

becomes

```xml
<security:http auto-config="true" access-denied-page="/denied.jsp" use-expressions="true">
```

And then:

```xml
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')" />
```

Answer (score 11):

I am not sure about this problem, actually I am using it currently in my project and don't see an issue. try removing the space after the "," I mean try using ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN

Comment: Teja you are right, it cannot handle spaces after the comma. It works fine without spaces.

Comment: The error message makes it clear that this is indeed the problem:
"Unsupported configuration attributes: [ ROLE_ADMIN]"

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem when was trying to migrate from Spring 3.x to 4.x. Finally I found that parameter "use-expressions" of "http" tag became "true" by default in Spring 4.x instead of false (as it was in old versions).

P.S. This question is very old for now, but I found this in Google. So somebody else can find it too and this info might be useful then.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469211/how-to-use-secauthorize-access-hasroleroles-for-checking-multiple-roles).

Use that line to grant access to user with both roles: 
`<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />`

If you want to grant access to user with one of the listed roles, use: 
`<security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />`

Also, you need to add ability to use SpEL in your security *.xml, add `use-expressions="true"` to `<http>` tag.

Answer (score -2):

I decided to downgrade to Spring Security 2.0.5 without changing anything else to check whether this was a bug in 3, and lo-and-behold it was!

I think I also found a related open bug here - https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1342

Solution - use 2.0.5 if want to use this feature.