# How to use <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLES)"> for checking multiple Roles?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to display some content conditionally based on Roles using Spring Security JSP taglibs.
But in Spring Security 3.1.x  is checking for only one role.

I can use  but **ifAllGranted** is deprecated.

Any help?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There is a special security expression in spring security:

> *hasAnyRole(list of roles)* - true if the user has been granted any of
>   the roles specified (given as a comma-separated list of strings).

I have never used it but I think it is exactly what you are looking for.

Example usage:

```
<security:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'DEVELOPER')">
    ...
</security:authorize>
```

Here is a [link to the reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) where the standard spring security expressions are described. Also, here is a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321696/creating-new-roles-and-permissions-dynamically-in-spring-security-3/10451102#10451102) where I described how to create custom expression if you need it.

Comment: It worked :-) <sec:authorize access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER','ROLE_ADMIN')">
   (User/Admin)
 </sec:authorize> But any way to check for hasAllRoles(role1, role2)?

Comment: About your last question: "But any way to check for hasAllRoles(role1, role2)?" - I don't think that it is possible. But you can crete your custom expression (I gave a link), and in code check whatever you want.

Comment: On your second question you should be able to use 'hasRole' with the 'and' operator like hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DEVELOPER') to achieve this functionality.

Comment: If you want to have content for people who have role1 AND role2, I suppose you could just nest two blocks.

Comment: `hasAnyRole` cannot logically replace `ifAllGranted`; please see my answer below

Answer (score 8):

@dimas's answer is not logically consistent with your question; `ifAllGranted` cannot be directly replaced with `hasAnyRole`.

From the [Spring Security 3—>4 migration guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-deprecations-taglibs):

Old:

```
<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER">
    <p>Must have ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER</p>
</sec:authorize>
```

New (SPeL):

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    <p>Must have ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER</p>
</sec:authorize>
```

Replacing `ifAllGranted` directly with `hasAnyRole` will cause spring to evaluate the statement using an `OR` instead of an `AND`.  That is, `hasAnyRole` will return `true` if the authenticated principal contains *at least one* of the specified roles, whereas Spring's (now deprecated as of Spring Security 4) `ifAllGranted` method only returned `true` if the authenticated principal contained *all* of the specified roles.

**TL;DR**: To replicate the behavior of `ifAllGranted` using Spring Security Taglib's new authentication Expression Language, the `hasRole('ROLE_1') and hasRole('ROLE_2')` pattern needs to be used.

Comment: Thank you very much. Also it works for privileges similarly.                  <div sec:authorize="hasAuthority('CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE')and hasAuthority('CREATE_GROUP')"> This text is only visible to an user who has the 'CREATE_GROUP' and 'CHANGE_PASSWORD_PRIVILEGE' privileges together.</div>

Answer (score 1):

i used `hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')` but i was getting bean creation below error

```
Error creating bean with name     'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource] while setting bean property 'securityMetadataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected a single expression attribute for [/user/*]
```

then i tried

`access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or hasRole('ROLE_USER')"` and it's working fine for me.

as one of my user is admin as well as user.

for this you need to add `use-expressions="true" auto-config="true"` followed by http tag

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" >.....</http>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try in this way if you are using thymeleaf

```
sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')"
```

hasAnyRole will return true if the authenticated principal contains at least one of the specified roles,false otherwise.

**Please note you have to use sec tag in your html declaration tag like this**

```
<html xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
```

Answer (score 1):

Within Spring Boot 2.4 it is

```
sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN')
```

Ensure that you have

> thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5

in your dependencies. Also make sure that you include the namespace

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security"
```

in your html...

Comment: What does including thymleaf in the namespace do .  I always take that out and haven't had problems yet.