# Java Spring Security AccessDecisionManager: UnanimousBased Failed to parse expression 'ROLE_ADMIN, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I try to make some simple rememmber me authentication with spring security, but I found this error when I try to implement accessDecisionManager. here the error log :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while
>   setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0':
>   Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0'
>   while setting constructor argument with key [10]; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0':
>   Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type
>   [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource]
>   while setting bean property 'securityMetadataSource'; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name '(inner bean)#19': Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not
>   instantiate bean class
>   [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to parse expression
>   'ROLE_ADMIN, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'

and this is my xml file.
web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring Security Eksplorasi</display-name>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>kampus</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>kampus</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

so this is my spring-security.xml

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
        <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
                    <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
                </beans:bean>
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
        <security:remember-me key="kampus-rememberme" data-source-ref="dataSource" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
        <security:form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />
        <!-- enable csrf protection 
        <csrf/>-->
    </security:http>
    <!-- 
    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
     -->

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query=
                    "select username,password, status from users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query=
                    "select username, role from user_roles where username =?  " />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

many thanks for your help friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you just need to remove blank space in access attribute:

```
access="ROLE_ADMIN, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"
```

to

```
access="ROLE_ADMIN,IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"
```

If this doesn't work, try it like:

```
access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN', 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')"
```

Similar question: [Spring Security 3 specify multiple intercept-url access roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103237/spring-security-3-specify-multiple-intercept-url-access-roles)

Check Teja's answer.

Comment: I have tried your, but the app still show the same error.

Comment: when I'm not using the accessDecisionManager bean and the access-decision-manager-ref atribute erased , the app run finely. the problem is I want use this bean for more secure, not just rememmber me. sorry for bad english :(

Comment: Then it might be related to the role prefix, you define `<beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>`, but your role `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` does not start with "ROLE_". Can you check that? Make it `ROLE_IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` just for testing.

Comment: its not work, rolePrefix definied for user role which definied in dataSource, and IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY is one of authenticatiedVoter variable. I have tried everything I can, and also search in google, but no one work..

Comment: is some depedency take effect to this? I used spring core, web, webmvc, jdbc, so spring security web, config, taglibs. is some library miss?

Answer (score 2):

You are using [expression based access control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) (default and you explicitly declare it with `use-expressions="true"`) and `ROLE_ADMIN, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY` is not a valid expression but an "old style" roles list so either set `use-expressions` to `false` or substitute the "old style" roles list with the expression `hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or isFullyAuthenticated()`

Comment: The part where I substitute old_style roles list with expressions worked for me. Thanks!