# hasRole() Spring Security not working

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, authentication

I did something like:

```
   <intercept-url pattern="/welcome" access = "hasRole 
   ('ROLE_USER') or  hasRole ('ROLE_OWNER')"/>
```

I can access this page as a user with role user but I cannot access this page as an user with a role owner.One user can only have one role (cannot be user and owner at the same time)Users are connected to roles via @ManyToMany and @Jointable- it works okay in the rest of an app,it just does  not work in here. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You should really include some code snippets that illustrate your problem, etc.  Otherwise, this question will likely be closed for being poorly asked.

Comment: Oh  I am really  sorry forgot  to add code instead of code.I will edit that in a moment! EDIT Done!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Security 3 specify multiple intercept-url access roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103237/spring-security-3-specify-multiple-intercept-url-access-roles)

Comment: Please see the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2105363/1572269